# Java Jtable coulmn shorting with date not working properly

Tags: java, swing, date, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Sorry for asking basic question once again. As new to java, so i thought better to take guidance instead of doing something stupid.

In my jtable, i have following data

```
Id | Name | Date(month-year)
1  | XYZ  | August-2014
2  | ABc  | April-2014
```

my Modelclass is as follows

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

 private String[] columnNames = {"Id", "Country","Date"};

 public final Object[] longValues = {Integer.class,"",Date.class};
```

now as recommended, i have overriden the getColumnClass in my model table

```
@Override
 public Class getColumnClass(int c)
 {
     if(c == 2)
     {
              //return Date.class;
              return getValueAt(0,c).getClass();
     }
      else
         return getValueAt(0,c).getClass();
  }
```

and i have enabled default column sorter.

Now as default, all string columns work fine in shorting but for Date column also it consider as string and short it as string.

If i force the column to short as date it give me error.

What am i doing wrong and what is correct way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: whats value that returns this column, is there Date.class in return, otherwise this question doesn't make me sence

Comment: for more info to read Oracle tutorial How to use Tables - part about renderers (description about data types)

Comment: Hi @mKorbel i have added some detail about model class, so that it make more readable.

Comment: you could get rid of the entire `if`/`else` by the look of those identical statements!  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Now as recommended, I have overriden the `getColumnClass` in my model table*

Note that your implementation is wrong mainly because you never have to ask for model's value to get the column's class (not to mention redundant/useless `if-else` block). Since you know your model then you are perfectly capable to return the right column class with no need to query the model:

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0: return Integer.class; // Id column
        case 1: return String.class; // Name column
        case 2: return Date.class; // Date column
            default: return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }
}
```

This should be enough to properly sort dates column, even if your renderer shows month-year pattern:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Date.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        if (value instanceof Date) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy");
            value = formatter.format((Date)value);
        }

        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }
});
```

For example if you have `9/27/2014` and `9/30/2014` then this should be the natural ascending order when you sort this column, regardless both cells display `September-2014`.

Comment: Hi @dic19, it solve the problem, but i didnt get table.setDefaultRenderer(Date.class , new DefaultTableCellRenderer), in this why did we mention Date.class, why we used it here

Comment: @javadotnetcoder: yes, `JTable` uses [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) to associate a data type with a custom renderer.

Answer (score 2):

Several things must work in concert:

- Let column two, labeled `Date`, return `Date.class` from `getColumnClass()`.
- Ensure that only values of type `Date.class` are added to the `TableModel`.
- Enforce the date format using a custom [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and suitable `DateFormat`, e.g. `"MMMM/yyyy"`, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).
- Adopt a convention regarding dates that are accurate to a month, e.g. first day of the month, and enforce it in your model's public interface.